# how to print currency symbols using webdriver with testng

Tags: selenium, webdriver, testng

**In Dropdown currencies are listed as($,€,₤). Based on the selected currency, prices will display in other page like ($10,€10,₤10). Using the below code, I got the selected value from the dropdown.**

```
    WebElement select=driver.findElement(By.className("selected"));
    select.getText();
    System.out.println("Currency Selected:" +select.getText());
```

**When I print the value its coming as ? instead of $. How to print the currency value. And check whether the $ currency is displaying in other page.**

Comment: Are you sure your terminal (or whatever you are using for output) is capable of printing currency symbols correctly?

Comment: Thanks. It worked after changing the console encoding to UTF-8

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer if you found it helpful. =)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of simple `System.out.println` (last line in your example)

**try out the following:**

```
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8");
out.println("Currency Selected:" +select.getText());
```